# npx react-native@latest init error installing ruby gems

Tags: ruby, react-native, rubygems, react-native-cli

While trying to create a react native CLI app on M1 Mac an error occured while installing Ruby Gems:

```
✖ Installing Ruby Gems
error There was an error while trying to write to
/Users/maciejwiacek/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/versions.61581.tmp.
It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.
✖ Installing Ruby Gems
error Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos&platform=android and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
```

I tried reinstalling my macos, cocoapods, ruby versions, homebrew, watchman etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ruby and cocoapods? [The official guide](https://cocoapods.org/) says that you would need to use `sudo` in some cases. I'm using [Ruby Version Manager](https://rvm.io/) installed thanks to [this guide](https://nrogap.medium.com/install-rvm-in-macos-step-by-step-d3b3c236953b), but previously I just get my work done with `sudo`, even if many discourages this practice.

Comment: After some guy told me I decided to reinstall everything once again from scratch. I did use ruby's version that comes with macos and I had to install cocoapods by homebrew. Luckily it fixed my problem. I think those errors were actually caused by installing ruby and/or cocoapods using sudo. Nonetheless thanks for your help!